# Sometimes wireless card doesn't detect anything. Toggling wireless doesn't help. Any fixes (excluding restarts)?

Tags: networking

It has happened a couple of times now, and it seems like different things can trigger it.

Most recently I used the switch on the side of thinkpad to turn off wifi to save battery. Put it to sleep when I was finished and next day it wouldn't detect wireless signals.

I've tried "sudo nservice networking restart" but it didn't seem to do anything. I've tried going into network setting and toggling the on/off switch but wasn't helping. Finally I restarted and it's working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found a solution.

For anyone else out there with same problem as me, try this:

- Go to terminal
- Type: sudo systemctl restart network-manager

Problem should be fixed.